# how to filter table according to data in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am using PostgreSQL in which there are 1000 tables but there is only 50 table which contain data so I want to filter that table and select only those table which has data in it.

I am not getting idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the information schema for that but be sure to VACUUM the database first (in the example I created indexes to force update);

```
SELECT t.tablename, c.reltuples from pg_tables t
JOIN pg_class c
ON c.relname = t.tablename
WHERE SCHEMANAME = 'public'
AND reltuples > 0;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5f96d/2)

Comment: ANALYZE is more important, VACUUM only touches dead tuples.

Comment: and note that this isn't *guaranteed* to return non-zero for a non-empty table. ANALYZE might sample pages that contain only dead rows; that doesn't mean there are no live rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is the SQL query to find all table names:

```
SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public'
```

and this is the SQL to return the number of rows in a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

where `table` is the name of the table. You want to combine these. There are several ways:

1) Write a stored procedure in [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/plpgsql.html). Basically you would have to loop over the results of the `SELECT tablename...` query, and for each table name construct the corresponding second query using the `EXECUTE` statement (details are [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)).

2) Use a PostgreSQL client library provided by your favourite programming language (e.g. [Psycopg2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for Python) and implement the same logic described above.

I hope you don't mind if I do not provide code, this should get you started.